# PostgreSQL CREATE DOMAIN equivalent in Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

In PostgreSQL, I used `CREATE DOMAIN` command to make a data type alias.

How to make same thing in Oracle? (11g, AWS RDS)

I mean a simple data type alias, not a structured data type.

Comment: Oracle does not have anything similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an alias, or a new type based on existing one, using the `SUBTYPE` command:

```sql
SUBTYPE subtype_name IS base_type [CONSTRAINTS];
```

For example:

```sql
SUBTYPE MYFLOAT IS NUMBER;

SUBTYPE BOOLCHAR IS VARCHAR2(1);

SUBTYPE DATENN IS DATE NOT NULL;
```

This only works in PL/SQL context.